# MySQL DB per day heavy records can impact performance?

Tags: mysql, performance, csv

I'm developing an application where new file created on FTP will be directly imported into DB and based upon the content of that file, I've to perform actions via my developing language. The file which is being created is a .csv file.

Now the question is that whether total size of CSV will impact the performance? Because there might be cases when the CSV file will contain over 100K rows and inserting all of them in mandatory as that is required. Three such files will be created on a time interval of approx 10-15 minutes.

Expected data volume is of at least 40 Million records per day. I have a strong doubt on this that whether this will impact performance too? However, as far as I know, DB size should not matter on performance but the queries, still do I need to flush the data on some time interval too or do I need to take care of anything which I have not even mentioned here?

Flow of my application is that one module will keep on reading these files to store data and perform required actions and save into respected fields of DB and another module will be using this processed data for viewing purpose.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

(It's unclear what processing you are doing; so I will make some guesses.)

You are inserting/processing hundred(s) of rows per second.  This will impact the system in various ways, but it should not be "too much".

If the table is a **replacement** for an existing table:

1. `CREATE TABLE tmp LIKE real;`
2. `LOAD DATA ... tmp ...;` -- load all 3 into the same table?
3. `RENAME TABLE real TO old, tmp TO real; DROP TABLE old;`

It may be better to create the table without any indexes other than the PRIMARY KEY, then add the indexes between steps 2 and 3.

If you just need to **munch** on the data and then throw it away:

1. `CREATE TABLE tmp ( ... ) ENGINE = MyISAM;`
2. `LOAD DATA ... tmp ...;` -- load all 3 into the same table?
3. Optionally add indexes to facilitate the munching.  (Doing after loading is probably faster.)
4. Do whatever munching you need.
5. `DROP TABLE tmp;`